# if user is in ADGroup evaluating incorrectly powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im trying to keep and AD group to date with an sql database table.  but i cannot get my logic to work correctly, here is a sample of what i mean:

```
    $group = "<ADGroupName>"
    $user = (Get-ADUser -Identity <sAMAccountName> -Properties MemberOf,sAMAccountName | Select-Object MemberOf,sAMAccountName)

    Function Add-ADUserToGroup{
        if ($user.MemberOf -notmatch $group){
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user.sAMAccountName
            }
        else{
            Wirte-Host "User is already a member of $group"
            }
        }

    Add-ADUserToGroup
```

if i put my sAMAccountName in the `$user` variable set, and if i exist the group specified in the `$group` variable, it still attempts to add me to group and fails because i already exist in the group.  i have tried other operands in place of the `-notmatch` such as `-notin` `-ne` but nothing seems to evaluate the if statement correctly and im not sure why.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$group = "<ADGroupName>"
$user = (Get-ADUser -Identity <sAMAccountName> -Properties MemberOf,sAMAccountName | Select-Object MemberOf,sAMAccountName)

Function Add-ADUserToGroup{
    if (-not ($user.MemberOf -match $group)){
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user.sAMAccountName
        }
    else{
        Wirte-Host "User is already a member of $group"
        }
    }

Add-ADUserToGroup
```

You're doing a match against an array, and then casting the result as [bool] in the IF.

`$user.MemberOf -notmatch $group` is going to return all the groups the user is a member of that don't match `$group`.  If that returns anything at all the result will be True for the IF, and it's probably always going to find some.

Comment: Not working for me using **match**. ROL_AGENCIA matchs with ***CN=ROL_AGENCIA*** and ***CN=NSI_ROL_AGENCIA*** I want only matchs with **CN=ROL_AGENCIA**

Comment: Then you have to qualify your match string some more.  See get-help about_regular_expressions.

Answer (score 0):

So, i found a solution, and it is in the operand.  so if i use this:

```
if ($user.MemberOf -notmatch $group){
     <Foo>
     }
```

the if statement does not evaluate correctly at all, however if i use this:

```
if (!($user.MemberOf -match $group)){
     <Foo>
     }
```

the if statement does evaluate correctly.  i don't have an explanation, but it works.